# Does nanopb have python support?

Tags: nanopb

Google protobufs have multi language support including languages like C/C++, python, ruby, Go, etc.

```sh
protoc --cpp_out o1 --java_out o2 --python_out o3
```

- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Protocol_Buffers#Language_support
- https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/overview

Does nanopb hold multi-language support or is it primarily targeting usage from `C`?

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer in the home page of the documentation which I missed.

> Nanopb is a **plain-C implementation** of Google's Protocol Buffers data format. It is targeted at 32 bit microcontrollers, but is also fit for other embedded systems with tight (<10 kB ROM, <1 kB RAM) memory constraints.
>
> https://jpa.kapsi.fi/nanopb/

---

### Background

I'm trying to wrangle google protobuf instances and convert them to nanopb types in a C++ python binding

Comment: Note that all protobuf libraries use the same binary format. So easiest solution is probably to serialize your messages before passing them to C.